# Control Raspberry Pi from PC without internet

Tags: pi-3b+, vnc

I got a Raspberry Pi 3b+ and I got a problem with my internet and I want to control my Pi with my MacBook. It should be like with a VNC server. But in the next time, I got no internet and want to go on coding from Mac. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: it is unclear why you require an internet connection in the first place ..... is your LAN connection somehow affected by the internet connection?

Comment: The only way to have something like VNC running is via an IP connection.  There does not actually have to be internet access, however -- you could run either your Mac or the Pi as a access point, and even if there is no internet, they will be able to connect to each other.  However, this is no easier than a normal internet configuration, so if the problem is you can't get the internet to work, this probably won't be an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

this could be usefull to you. The configutarion described in this post, allow to the RPi, detect a connection to the router. If the RPi can't connect to the router, the RPi auto create an Access Point (you can configure the name, ip and password). So you can connect your notebook to the AP generated by the RPi and then access to the RPi using ssh. The problem is that in the latter case you do not have access to the internet, unless you have the pi connected by ethernet and properly configured.

source: http://www.raspberryconnect.com/network/item/331-raspberry-pi-auto-wifi-hotspot-switch-direct-connection

regards

Answer (score 0):

On your Mac open up a terminal window. Enter the text:

`ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`

If this doesn't work, you can use the app 'Fing' on an iPhone or Android device to get the IP address of the Pi and use that instead of `raspberrypi.local`

Password is raspberry by default and should be personalised as soon as possible.